# Getting user input in android game

Tags: android, canvas, input, keyboard

I am building my first android app which is a simple game. I have done it by extending Activity class and using 2D graphics to draw to the screen by using Canvas (for learning purposes).

Now I would like to get user / player initials and I need something like a component to read it. I could go about and draw a keyboard on my own and bind touch listeners to it  / read touch events but I have understood there's already something similar in Android, like software keyboard. One option I was thinking was to use EditText component.

Can I render either the software keyboard or EditText component by using Canvas? EditText and KeyBoardView seem to have method **draw(Canvas canvas)**. Would that be the right way to do it? How would I set the coordinates where to draw the component to?

If that would work, the layout and general look and feel are not probably inline with the Game look and feel, would that be a correct assumption? (which means I would still need to implement it myself?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the software keyboard might disrupt your game's look and feel. Nonetheless, if your game is the
simple type, you can just place an `EditText` on your activity's view like this:

```
FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);

layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
EditText eTInitials = new EditText(this);  
eTInitials.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 5); //change to suit your game
eTInitials.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.BOTTOM); //change to suit your game
etInitials.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){ [override onkeymethod here]   }); //get player initials here
layout.addView(yourView);

layout.addView(eTInitials);
setContentView(layout);
```

I remember saving my high score on a 3D game via the software keyboard so this approach isn't that bad.

Or as you said, you can implement it yourself by drawing your own custom keyboard bitmap and reading the touch events.

Comment: This is probably how it would work, I am sure. I cannot get this working though because my game contains "screens" or "views" on it's own and I would need to use EditText on one of those "screens". I get an exception which is basically thrown because I try to draw from worker thread instead of UI thread.

Comment: In your activity just set the EditText visibility to "gone", create a listener with a method that sets it back to "visible" then call it in those "screens" when needed.

Comment: I see. How about if I would have tens of widgets I would like to use for different purposes? I would need to instantiate them all in my Activity, set visibility to Gone and use listeners? This seems a bit clumsy since I would like each class to be responsible for their own activities and not to have a single massive class containing all variables etc. If I would be doing this in openGL, I probably couldn't use the widgets at all, but I think my problem is a bit similar. I have a "screen" that is not drawn by UI thread, something I would think the openGL version would have too?

Comment: No, you can use the widgets in openGL too. Remember! most great android games out there have ad banners and these banners are widgets/views just like EditText. Are your screens bound to one activity or each screen has its own activity? The latter approach has its own downsides but would resolve your problem, else you'd have to draw your own custom keyboard.

Comment: I have currently just one activity. This might the source of the problems and I might have to change it later since I will be trying those banners too. Currently this is what I ended up doing: http://www.flickr.com/photos/60978799@N03/10107513736/ Of course, it's work in progress but will do for now ;)

Comment: Nice. Handle "key codes" for "backspace", "spacebar" e.t.c and you'll end up a library other game devs can use in their games ;) Of course, if you want to :)